# Is it advisable to use non-scientific method to teach science courses?

Tags: writing, books

This question is motivated after reading a pop-science book from a famous researcher about physics and some implications. I find the content *very* amusing but I was utterly frustrated at the lack of *any* scientific value.

In particular, the book is about some *plausible* explanations about some observed *fact*. The author tells a story as follows:

*Event A *could* occur under some wild assumptions. If A occurs and a sequence of events B occur, then an event C has non-zero possibility to occur. So, A is potentially responsible for C.*

I.e., if something *could* happen, let's write a book about it (about A => C) without absolutely any supporting scientific evidence for A or B. It doesn't matter if C could occur for a gazillion other non-related and more plausible issues.

Such exposition reminds me the famous argument that a rocket launch *could* (in principle) alter the rotation of the earth and a change on its rotation *could* alter the climate. So, if we observe a change in the climate together with *any* change in the rotation, we should blame NASA.

I wonder why, otherwise prominent, scientists follow such populist and counter-scientific way of exposition. Could this qualify as *pseudo-science*?

My question related to academic standards and ethics, motivated by the above incident, is the following:

- Do the ends (of drawing more people into science) justify the means (doing so by an exaggerated non-scientific way)? This is not limited to a single pop-sci book.
- Can this be applied to standard university level pedagogy? Is it advisable to teach any scientific topic using a non-scientific way with the hope that more students find it appealing?
- Are there specific examples of such successful pedagogical method?
- Is this a contradiction?

*Note:* Initially, this post created some controversy, and subsequently was voted for closing, for being very opinion-made. I tried to adapt the text and the questions to reflect more objectified answers related to ways of teaching in academic environment. In other words *if it is OK to teach the public about scientific matters in a non-scientific way, could we do the same in class*? Do you have any particular examples, successful or not, in mind?

Comment: Does the book (or its author) claim to make any prediction that C is indeed going to happen, rather than just describing a scientifically sound what-if scenario?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It is not scientifically sound what-if. It is an attempt to explain (based on very little) that C could have happened because of A. The paradigm with NASA I provided summarized very well the point of the paper.  It might be a _credible_ (and sexy) hypothesis, but is based on_zero_ evidence.

Comment: This question looks like a rant about a specific, anonymous book. In particular, I do not see any answer we could question here: 1) We cannot tell you whether your specific book is sound, because we do not know it. Even if we did, that question would be off-topic here. 2) We cannot answer you why the other wrote the book the way they did, because we cannot read minds. 3) Even if this is a general phenomenon (for which you do not provide any evidence), we can only speculate why authors are writing the way they do.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft If you think it's off topic, that's fine. Look my comment to the TheDarkSide below: do the ends justify the actions of such writers to present scientific material in such a non-scientific way? I think it's a well posed question, not limited to a particular book.

Comment: *do the ends justify the actions* – That’s still primarily opinion-based. At best you could ask about **established** ethical standards for writing a popular-science book.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I rephrased my question to reflect a general phenomenon on  (1) Requirements and expectations of academicians
(2) University-level pedagogy. Hope this makes the question on-topic.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I understand your point and I try to make my question as less opinion based as possible. If you think that my question _can_ be rephrased in such a way so as to not generate opinion based answers, feel free to edit.  I believe it's a well posed and _objective_ question about the standards in scientific expositions/teaching methods.

Comment: Since the question has been downvoted  I changed the content and the nature of my question to comply with the instruction given in the Help-Center. In particular my question now is clearly about (1) Requirements and expectations of academicians (2) University-level pedagogy and I tried to minimize opinion generated content.  I hope that it will be re-opened because I think this is a relevant academic question.

Comment: @PsySp - I saw your reopen flag, but I must say that I do agree with Wrzlprmft that this question will still necessarily lead to almost entirely opinion-based answers. I appreciate that your question is a good one, but it doesn't match the type of question we look for on this particular site.

Comment: @eykanal Thank you for your time and for your comment. I appreciate it. If you think that the question cannot be altered, then feel free to delete or close it (or make a suggestion to transfer to another stackExchange forum). Thanks again and I apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: No worries, it can stay here closed. I don't know of another place on the SE network where this will fit.

Answer (score 3):

"What if..." Is the bread and butter of science and mathematics. Making outrageous guesses and then checking them is part of the toolkit for professional thinkers.

In your examples, you say that the author takes the stance that one event only *potentially* explains another, which seems fine from a scientific point of view.

As others have said, when you popularize you often intentionally leave out some subtlety. This is really a function of your intended audience. I leave out some subtlety when I teach intro calculus.

As to whether or not the author you reference does this badly or irresponsibly, I can't form an opinion without reading what they wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not exactly a "what-if" scenario and it is not the case where the author just takes away the subtleties. It's a scenario along the lines: "Theory A is peculiar and weird. Theory B is also peculiar and weird. So let's use A to crudely explain B even if it doesn't make any scientific sense and is not supported by _any_ evidence". How does this promotes scientific thinking, is beyond me but maybe I have a blind spot. Thus the question.

Comment: I agree, but with limitations. "we could see anything -> dinossaurs" for instance ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_N_IYi2c0E )

Answer (score 3):

As others have already expressed, I think this is hard to answer decisively because you have a specific work in mind whose perceived flaws you are describing in very general terms.  You write

> Event A *could* occur under some assumptions. If A occurs and a sequence of events B occur, then an event C has non-zero possibility to occur. So, A is potentially responsible for C.
>
> I.e., if something could happen, let's write a book about it without absolutely any supporting scientific evidence for A or B. It doesn't matter if C could occur for a gazillion other non-related and more plausible issues.

I think that I have read both good and bad books that fit this general description.  Whether it is good or bad depends upon the details: e.g. how interesting / novel / thought-provoking that A is potentially responsible for C even if it is not carefully argued for in any way?  Or, how potentially irresponsible / risky could such an allegation be?

I can however answer some of your questions:

> Does this [qualify] as pseudo-science as opposed to pop-science?

A key hallmark of pseudo-science is that it claims to be science but does not follow the scientific method (at least not competently and in good faith).  A popular book written by a scientist is probably not science at all -- it does not claim to follow the scientific method, be published or not based on its intellectual novelty and scientific rigor, and so forth.  It is indeed not necessary to be scientific when one writes about science in a popular way.

I don't intend this as *carte blanche*: a scientist can certainly write a popular science book that is bad or even scientifically irresponsible.  If the author takes advantage of the "lowering of the net" in order to promote something *as science* that in fact has not been subjected to scientific standards, then the work could have pseudo-scientific aspects.

> Do the ends (of drawing more people into science) justify the means (doing so by an exaggerated non-scientific way)?

Again, it depends very much on the work and how it is done.  But it is difficult, sometimes impossible, to be widely appealing and completely rigorous, and some of the most successful popular science books (where success is measured by drawing readers into actual science) have not met the highest standards of scientific rigor.

> Is this a contradiction?

Again, no, because the popularization of science is not science.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since the question was voted down for closing, I tried to put the question in a wider, more academic, and less opinion-based framework limited by few pop-sci books. I think any pop-sci book should, at least mildly, be scientific on every aspect. Otherwise what is the difference with bribing students to follow science?

Comment: @PsySp: "I think any pop-sci book should, at least mildly, be scientific on every aspect." That's such a general assertion that I have no ambition to disagree with it.  "Otherwise what is the difference with bribing students to follow science?" Here you've lost me a bit: if I bribe you, I give you money; if you buy my book, you give me money.  So that's one difference.  But more fundamentally: getting someone interested in something is very different from artificially inducing them to do it.

Comment: For me, an example of a very influential popular book is E.T. Bell's *Men of Mathematics*.  For the last 80 years it has drawn a lot of young people into mathematics by describing the lives and mathematics of some famous mathematicians (one of them a woman; anyway, the title would certainly not fly nowadays) in an entertaining, flowery way.  It turns out that these biographies are often somewhere between embroidered and invented.  The mathematics is more accurate but not amazing.  Nevertheless it is a good popular book.

Comment: What I mean is that when you try to lure in a reader into science by a crudely non-scientific argument, this qualifies as artificially inducing them to because they would have a very distorted view on what science and scientific methods are.

Comment: The books I was referring to are good pop books also! I had fun reading them. I just cannot easily digest such a profound lack of scientific methods in books that want to "popularize" science.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite a grey area.

Please note that the very objective of a popular-science work is to popularize relatively-complicated scientific subject, into a simpler, more-palatable form which a non-technical or semi-technical audience can read and get drawn into. This is intended to (over some course of time) trickle down and bring more people into science. That's not a bad goal, to say the least.

Now the problem is in deciding to what extent you simplify the complex subject. Naturally, there has to be some simplification, otherwise the product may be too complex for the masses. But with too many approximations, the final product may not bear any resemblance to the actual scientific work at all. It is a difficult tightrope walk, erring on either side will be bad.

Different people will have different yardsticks for which side do they want to err on. More scientifically scrupulous gentlemen would prefer to err on the side of caution, so that even with the simplifications, no one reads badly about their scientific credentials. But there will always be a more extravagant variety, which will take the liberty of a popular-science theme to create an over-enthusiastic presentation of the subject that may dilute the science. Sometimes, people hold that against some of the more famed science-popularizers of our times.

However, provided one understands what someone is trying to accomplish with a popular science work, it is advisable not to take offense with these simplifications. Also please note that science-fiction and popular-science are actually quite distinct: the fiction part in the former is scientifically implausible (and that can be established). In more extravagant popular science, you are still dealing with a soft subject, which is scientifically honest in the sense that it is still a possibility, less probable as it may be!

Go easy on the poor popularizers :)

Comment: I am a big fan of pop-sci books, especially on physics, cosmology etc. I do not mind crude approximations on the scientific matters. What I mind though is a crude approximation on the scientific _thinking_. The exposition I described is far from _how_ an scientist would think to derive conclusions and it might give a very wrong impression of the scientific thinking to the layman.

Comment: Another point: If a pop-science author wants to create a sci-fi scenario in the course of which s/he explains heavy sci stuff, that's actually awesome. But my concern is how the exposition is perceived by the non-scientist layman. _Does anything plausible qualifies as scientific?_

Comment: "the fiction part in the former is scientifically implausible" - I disagree with that statement in its general sense; hard science fiction is not scientifically implausible, it is just based on speculative elements. Even not-so-hard science fiction is not necessarily scientifically implausible; it is just based on quite a bit more speculation than the bare minimum required for the setting.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Yes you are right. That sentence came out harder than I envisaged. I'll probably go easy on that and revise it. :)

Comment: @PsySp - While it is difficult for me to make specific comments about the situation without knowing the exact details, my point is that the author is not even attempting a scientifically rigorous account. The idea is, if that approximate presentation suffices to draw people into science, the job of the text is done. While "anything plausible" may not "qualify as scientific", when you've drawn people into science, reading more scientifically accurate works about the same subject would happen eventually. When that happens, the reader would eventually look back at pop-sci, & deem it approximate.

Comment: @TheDarkSide I tried to make an as accurate as possible description on the content and the exposition of the book. I do not want to name it. But my question is whether such _strategy_ promotes the scientific _thinking_. Do the ends (draw people into science) justify the means (exposition in a non-scientific way of -nevertheless- relevant scientific ideas).

Comment: @PsySp - Like I said in the answer, it is a grey area, and is very debatable. There can be no general answer to this question, having universal applicability. The stance that I'm advocating is - yes, in certain situations (as explained above). :)

Comment: @TheDarkSide Thanks. My opinion is that scientists should be consistent when promoting science. But that is just my opinion, and I am open to different interpretations (yours included!)